# Encode algorithm QR-code

Tags: qr-code

Who knows how to generate qr-code?
And how to decorate like here http://mojiq.kazina.com/?

Comment: All I wanted to know is if it uses compression or not, or how does it deal with reducing the data size, but I'm quite disappoint: are we really asking questions so that people just answers "read the ISO document" ?

Comment: (advertising:) There's a documented Lua library that encodes data into QRCodes: http://speedata.github.com/luaqrcode/

Answer (score 32):

try this **tutorial** http://www.thonky.com/qr-code-tutorial/, very good in-depth tutorial on creating QR-codes, but only for a certain type of QR-code.

Comment: Beware, there seems to be a few errors in the tutorial. The generated QR code and the page "Show polynomial division steps" look very suspicious to me. (For example (α * α^210) is not α^210, but α^211.) Otherwise an excellent resource.

Comment: back then, when I stepped through this tutorial those parts didn't exist. Basically those parts were my idea, since I had some serious trouble with them. But think it must be a typo, because (for me) everything works just fine.

Comment: One implementation, based partially on the thornky tutorial mentioned above is located [here](https://github.com/shieldui/shieldui-lite). 
An example of a jquery plugin using this approach is available [here](http://demos.shieldui.com/web/qrcode/api).

Answer (score 9):

Most of the time, the problem is the Finite-Field arithmetic, because it is a little bit different. And once you have the generator working, the error-correction techniques make it harder to see if the code is generated correctly. There is another site which has ECC generator: http://www.pclviewer.com/rs2/calculator.html
But note that this generator also does not work correctly in all cases, same as Thonky's error code correction generator.

A small project I made allows step-by-step debugging and following the creation of the QRCode and manually changing all the parameters - something no generator on web does. The link: https://github.com/Legoless/QRCode

Comment: Did not receive anything, where did you send it to?

Comment: Thank you, will post a fix. ;)

Comment: There is a new version of the QRCode with additional comments and bug fixes posted. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Last article link is dead, seems this is a good entry point: http://www.arvystate.net/portfolio/densowave-qrcode-encoding-standard-in-net/

Comment: @JeroenWiertPluimers, thanks, updated. Forgot about it when redesigning the page.

Comment: @KenB, I closed the website, but the project is available on GitHub: https://github.com/Legoless/QRCode. I fixed the link.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ZXing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/)'s [GAE app](http://zxing.appspot.com/) to [generate QR codes](http://zxing.appspot.com/generator/) in a browser, or download the Java library and use the `zxing.appspot.com` component in your own code.

Comment: Thank you, but I am interested in the mathematical algorithm

Comment: Start by reading [this](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/BarcodeContents), or you can browse the ZXing source code to see how they implement it.

Comment: Basic encoder classes: [`com.google.zxing.qrcode.encoder`](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/core/src/com/google/zxing/qrcode/encoder/). Specifically, see [`Encoder.java`](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/core/src/com/google/zxing/qrcode/encoder/Encoder.java).

Comment: Ok it's first step. How transformate this message in QR-code. I found [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:QR_Code_Structure_Example.svg) and I now that QR-code use Reed-Solomon Code for Error Correction.

Comment: Could you clarify that? I don't understand what you mean by "How transformate this message in QR-code."

Comment: I have text message. For Qr-code I need to encode this message to binary. For example, in barcode use encoding table. And how encode format information and version information?

Answer (score 1):

you can use the JavaScript  implementation of a QR symbology, which is part of the ShieldUI open source package available [here](https://github.com/shieldui/shieldui-lite). 
You can see a jquery QR plugin implementation based on it in the following [demo](http://demos.shieldui.com/web/qrcode/api).