# Why does this VBA-generated QR-Code stutter? (barcode-vba-macro-only)

Tags: vba, excel, qr-code

### Context

I am using [barcode-vba-macro-only](https://code.google.com/archive/p/barcode-vba-macro-only/) (mentioned in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31663859/669202)) in MS Excel 2010 to generate a QR code.

*(The bar code will be used to facilitate paying a bill using [Girocode](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Girocode), but that is not important here, except to say I need to structure the input exactly the way shown below.)*

### The problem

The VBA macro creates great QR-Codes, but somehow, when given certain input, the output (encoded in the QR code) "stutters", i.e. repeats part of the text.

E.g., when given this input:

```
BCD
001
1
SCT
SOLADES1HDB
Recipient First and Last Name
DE86672500200000123456
EUR123.45
```

it produces this output:

[image: QR-code generated by the VBA macro]

which oddly repeats part of the content:

```
BCD
001
1
SCT
SOLADES1HDB
Recipient First and Last Name
DE
Recipient First and Last Name
DE86672500200000123456
EUR123.45
```

(Note the **DE** and the line **Recipient First and Last Name** which appear twice.)

### What I want

A working, free/GPL solution in Excel to generate such codes ;-) ... for example by understanding why this happens, and fixing the VBA code.

### What I have tried (Update 1)

1. I have played around with different inputs and found that just adding some extra "AAA" to the end of the long number solves the stuttering... so I am intrigued what causes this.
2. I forked to code on GitHub, added some code comments and translated a few of the existing (Czech) comments
3. **Through some debugging**, I found that the implementation messes up the starting position of different encodings (which it stores in array `eb`): after encoding the "Recipient First and Last Name" including newline and "DE" as "Byte", it probably tries to switch to "Decimal" or "Alphanum" encoding (only 3.33 or 5.5 bit per character instead of 8)... but then falls back to encoding in "Byte" format and thereby gets the starting position wrong.

### The code

You can download my test XLSM file [here](https://app.box.com/s/6i2ih68i5o07w3xu8oc3q6iulexagx9p), and access my [improved code file on GitHub](https://github.com/JonasHeidelberg/barcode-vba-macro-only/blob/Excel/barcody.bas).

I think the issue is probably in the core function shown below, in the section where the array `eb()` is filled.

```
Function qr_gen(ptext As String, poptions As String) As String
  Dim encoded1() As Byte ' byte mode (ASCII) all max 3200 bytes
  Dim encix1%
  Dim ecx_cnt(3) As Integer
  Dim ecx_pos(3) As Integer
  Dim ecx_poc(3) As Integer
  Dim eb(1 To 20, 1 To 4) As Integer 'store how many characters should be in which ECI mode. This is a list of rows, each row corresponding a the next batch of characters with a different ECI mode.
  ' eb(i, 1) - ECI mode (1 = numeric, 2 = alphanumeric, 3 = byte)
  ' eb(i, 2) - last character in previous row
  ' eb(i, 3) - number of characters in THIS row
  ' eb(i, 4) - number of bits for THIS row
  Dim ascimatrix$, mode$, err$
  Dim ecl%, r%, c%, mask%, utf8%, ebcnt%
  Dim i&, j&, k&, m&
  Dim ch%, s%, siz%
  Dim x As Boolean
  Dim qrarr() As Byte ' final matrix
  Dim qrpos As Integer
  Dim qrp(15) As Integer     ' 1:version,2:size,3:ccs,4:ccb,5:totby,6-12:syncs(7),13-15:versinfo(3)
  Dim qrsync1(1 To 8) As Byte
  Dim qrsync2(1 To 5) As Byte

  ascimatrix = ""
  err = ""
  mode = "M"
  i = InStr(poptions, "mode=")
  If i > 0 Then mode = Mid(poptions, i + 5, 1)
' M=0,L=1,H=2,Q=3
  ecl = InStr("MLHQ", mode) - 1
  If ecl < 0 Then mode = "M": ecl = 0
  If ptext = "" Then
    err = "Not data"
    Exit Function
  End If
  For i = 1 To 3
    ecx_pos(i) = 0
    ecx_cnt(i) = 0
    ecx_poc(i) = 0
  Next i
  ebcnt = 1
  utf8 = 0
  For i = 1 To Len(ptext) + 1
    ' Decide how many bytes this character has
    If i > Len(ptext) Then
      k = -5 ' End of text --> skip several code sections
    Else ' need to parse character i of ptext and decide how many bytes it has
      k = AscL(Mid(ptext, i, 1))
      If k >= &H1FFFFF Then ' FFFF - 1FFFFFFF
        m = 4
        k = -1
      ElseIf k >= &H7FF Then ' 7FF-FFFF 3 bytes
        m = 3
        k = -1
      ElseIf k >= 128 Then
        m = 2
        k = -1
      Else ' normal 7bit ASCII character, so it is worth it to check if it belong to the Numeric or Alphanumeric subsets defined in ECI (array qralnum)
        m = 1
        k = InStr(qralnum, Mid(ptext, i, 1)) - 1
      End If
    End If
    ' Depending on k and a lot of other things, increase ebcnt
    If (k < 0) Then ' Treat mult-byte case or exit? (bude byte nebo konec)
      If ecx_cnt(1) >= 9 Or (k = -5 And ecx_cnt(1) = ecx_cnt(3)) Then ' Until now it was possible numeric??? (Az dosud bylo mozno pouzitelne numeric)
        If (ecx_cnt(2) - ecx_cnt(1)) >= 8 Or (ecx_cnt(3) = ecx_cnt(2)) Then ' pred num je i pouzitelny alnum
          If (ecx_cnt(3) > ecx_cnt(2)) Then ' Jeste pred alnum bylo byte
            eb(ebcnt, 1) = 3         ' Typ byte
            eb(ebcnt, 2) = ecx_pos(3) ' Position pozice
            eb(ebcnt, 3) = ecx_cnt(3) - ecx_cnt(2) ' delka
            ebcnt = ebcnt + 1
            ecx_poc(3) = ecx_poc(3) + 1
          End If
          eb(ebcnt, 1) = 2         ' Typ alnum
          eb(ebcnt, 2) = ecx_pos(2)
          eb(ebcnt, 3) = ecx_cnt(2) - ecx_cnt(1) ' delka
          ebcnt = ebcnt + 1
          ecx_poc(2) = ecx_poc(2) + 1
          ecx_cnt(2) = 0
        ElseIf ecx_cnt(3) > ecx_cnt(1) Then ' byly bytes pred numeric
          eb(ebcnt, 1) = 3         ' Typ byte
          eb(ebcnt, 2) = ecx_pos(3) ' Position pozice
          eb(ebcnt, 3) = ecx_cnt(3) - ecx_cnt(1) ' delka
          ebcnt = ebcnt + 1
          ecx_poc(3) = ecx_poc(3) + 1
        End If
      ElseIf (ecx_cnt(2) >= 8) Or (k = -5 And ecx_cnt(2) = ecx_cnt(3)) Then ' Az dosud bylo mozno pouzitelne alnum
        If (ecx_cnt(3) > ecx_cnt(2)) Then ' Jeste pred alnum bylo byte
          eb(ebcnt, 1) = 3         ' Typ byte
          eb(ebcnt, 2) = ecx_pos(3) ' Position pozice
          eb(ebcnt, 3) = ecx_cnt(3) - ecx_cnt(2) ' delka
          ebcnt = ebcnt + 1
          ecx_poc(3) = ecx_poc(3) + 1
        End If
        eb(ebcnt, 1) = 2         ' Typ alnum
        eb(ebcnt, 2) = ecx_pos(2)
        eb(ebcnt, 3) = ecx_cnt(2) ' delka
        ebcnt = ebcnt + 1
        ecx_poc(2) = ecx_poc(2) + 1
        ecx_cnt(3) = 0
        ecx_cnt(2) = 0 ' vse zpracovano
      ElseIf (k = -5 And ecx_cnt(3) > 0) Then ' konec ale mam co ulozit
        eb(ebcnt, 1) = 3         ' Typ byte
        eb(ebcnt, 2) = ecx_pos(3) ' Position pozice
        eb(ebcnt, 3) = ecx_cnt(3) ' delka
        ebcnt = ebcnt + 1
        ecx_poc(3) = ecx_poc(3) + 1
      End If
    End If
    If k = -5 Then Exit For
    If (k >= 0) Then ' We can alphanumeric? (Muzeme alnum)
      If (k >= 10 And ecx_cnt(1) >= 12) Then ' Until now it was perhaps numeric (Az dosud bylo mozno num)
        If (ecx_cnt(2) - ecx_cnt(1)) >= 8 Or (ecx_cnt(3) = ecx_cnt(2)) Then ' There is also an alphanumeric which is worth it(Je tam i alnum ktery stoji za to)
          If (ecx_cnt(3) > ecx_cnt(2)) Then ' Even before it was alnum byte (Jeste pred alnum bylo byte)
            eb(ebcnt, 1) = 3         ' Typ byte
            eb(ebcnt, 2) = ecx_pos(3) ' Position (pozice)
            eb(ebcnt, 3) = ecx_cnt(3) - ecx_cnt(2) ' length (delka)
            ebcnt = ebcnt + 1
            ecx_poc(3) = ecx_poc(3) + 1
          End If
          eb(ebcnt, 1) = 2         ' Typ alnum
          eb(ebcnt, 2) = ecx_pos(2)
          eb(ebcnt, 3) = ecx_cnt(2) - ecx_cnt(1) ' length (delka)
          ebcnt = ebcnt + 1
          ecx_poc(2) = ecx_poc(2) + 1
          ecx_cnt(2) = 0 ' processed everything (vse zpracovano)
        ElseIf (ecx_cnt(3) > ecx_cnt(1)) Then ' Previous Num is byte (Pred Num je byte)
          eb(ebcnt, 1) = 3         ' Typ byte
          eb(ebcnt, 2) = ecx_pos(3) ' Position (pozice)
          eb(ebcnt, 3) = ecx_cnt(3) - ecx_cnt(1) ' length (delka)
          ebcnt = ebcnt + 1
          ecx_poc(3) = ecx_poc(3) + 1
        End If
        eb(ebcnt, 1) = 1         ' Typ numerix
        eb(ebcnt, 2) = ecx_pos(1)
        eb(ebcnt, 3) = ecx_cnt(1) ' length (delka)
        ebcnt = ebcnt + 1
        ecx_poc(1) = ecx_poc(1) + 1
        ecx_cnt(1) = 0
        ecx_cnt(2) = 0
        ecx_cnt(3) = 0 ' processed everything (vse zpracovano)
      End If
      If ecx_cnt(2) = 0 Then ecx_pos(2) = i
      ecx_cnt(2) = ecx_cnt(2) + 1
    Else ' possible alnum (mozno alnum)
      ecx_cnt(2) = 0
    End If
    If k >= 0 And k < 10 Then ' Can be numeric (muze byt numeric)
      If ecx_cnt(1) = 0 Then ecx_pos(1) = i
      ecx_cnt(1) = ecx_cnt(1) + 1
    Else
      ecx_cnt(1) = 0
    End If
    If ecx_cnt(3) = 0 Then ecx_pos(3) = i
    ecx_cnt(3) = ecx_cnt(3) + m
    utf8 = utf8 + m
    If ebcnt >= 16 Then ' We have already taken 3 other blocks of bits (Uz by se mi tri dalsi bloky stejne nevesli)
      ecx_cnt(1) = 0
      ecx_cnt(2) = 0
    End If
    Debug.Print "Character:'" & Mid(ptext, i, 1) & "'(" & k & _
        ") ebn=" & ecx_pos(1) & "." & ecx_cnt(1) & _
         " eba=" & ecx_pos(2) & "." & ecx_cnt(2) & _
         " ebb=" & ecx_pos(3) & "." & ecx_cnt(3)
  Next
  ebcnt = ebcnt - 1 ' ebcnt now has its final value
  Debug.Print ("ebcnt=" & ebcnt)
  c = 0
  For i = 1 To ebcnt
    Select Case eb(i, 1)
      Case 1: eb(i, 4) = Int(eb(i, 3) / 3) * 10 + (eb(i, 3) Mod 3) * 3 + IIf((eb(i, 3) Mod 3) > 0, 1, 0)
      Case 2: eb(i, 4) = Int(eb(i, 3) / 2) * 11 + (eb(i, 3) Mod 2) * 6
      Case 3: eb(i, 4) = eb(i, 3) * 8
    End Select
    c = c + eb(i, 4)
  Next i
  Debug.Print ("c=" & c)
'  UTF-8 is default not need ECI value - zxing cannot recognize
'  Call qr_params(i * 8 + utf8,mode,qrp)
  Call qr_params(c, ecl, qrp, ecx_poc)
  If qrp(1) <= 0 Then
    err = "Too long"
    Exit Function
  End If
  siz = qrp(2)
Debug.Print "ver:" & qrp(1) & mode & " size " & siz & " ecc:" & qrp(3) & "x" & qrp(4) & " d:" & (qrp(5) - qrp(3) * qrp(4))
'MsgBox "ver:" & qrp(1) & mode & " size " & siz & " ecc:" & qrp(3) & "x" & qrp(4) & " d:" & (qrp(5) - qrp(3) * qrp(4))
  ReDim encoded1(qrp(5) + 2)
  ' Table 3 — Number of bits in character count indicator for QR Code 2005:
  ' mode indicator (1=num,2=AlNum,4=Byte,8=kanji,ECI=7)
  '      mode: Byte Alphanum  Numeric  Kanji
  ' ver 1..9 :  8      9       10       8
  '   10..26 : 16     11       12      10
  '   27..40 : 16     13       14      12
' UTF-8 is default not need ECI value - zxing cannot recognize
'  if utf8 > 0 Then
'    k = &H700 + 26 ' UTF-8=26 ; Win1250 = 21; 8859-2 = 4 viz http://strokescribe.com/en/ECI.html
'    bb_putbits(encoded1,encix1,k,12)
'  End If
  encix1 = 0
  For i = 1 To ebcnt
    Select Case eb(i, 1)
      Case 1: c = IIf(qrp(1) < 10, 10, IIf(qrp(1) < 27, 12, 14)): k = 2 ^ c + eb(i, 3) ' encoding mode "Numeric"
      Case 2: c = IIf(qrp(1) < 10, 9, IIf(qrp(1) < 27, 11, 13)): k = 2 * (2 ^ c) + eb(i, 3) ' encoding mode "alphanum
      Case 3: c = IIf(qrp(1) < 10, 8, 16): k = 4 * (2 ^ c) + eb(i, 3) ' encoding mode "Byte"
    End Select
    Call bb_putbits(encoded1, encix1, k, c + 4)
    Debug.Print "ver:" & qrp(1) & mode & " size " & siz & " ecc:" & qrp(3) & "x" & qrp(4) & " d:" & (qrp(5) - qrp(3) * qrp(4))
    j = 0 ' count characters that have been output in THIS row eb(i,...)
    m = eb(i, 2) 'Start (after) last character of input from previous row
    r = 0
    While j < eb(i, 3)
      k = AscL(Mid(ptext, m, 1))
      m = m + 1
      If eb(i, 1) = 1 Then
        ' parse numeric input - output 3 decimal digits into 10 bit
        r = (r * 10) + ((k - &H30) Mod 10)
        If (j Mod 3) = 2 Then
          Call bb_putbits(encoded1, encix1, r, 10)
          r = 0
        End If
        j = j + 1
      ElseIf eb(i, 1) = 2 Then
        ' parse alphanumeric input - output 2 alphanumeric characters into 11 bit
        r = (r * 45) + ((InStr(qralnum, Chr(k)) - 1) Mod 45)
        If (j Mod 2) = 1 Then
          Call bb_putbits(encoded1, encix1, r, 11)
          r = 0
        End If
        j = j + 1
      Else
        ' Okay, byte mode: coding according to Chapter "6.4.2 Extended Channel Interpretation (ECI) mode" of ISOIEC 18004_2006Cor 1_2009.pdf
        If k > &H1FFFFF Then ' FFFF - 1FFFFFFF
          ch = &HF0 + Int(k / &H40000) Mod 8
          Call bb_putbits(encoded1, encix1, ch, 8)
          ch = 128 + Int(k / &H1000) Mod 64
          Call bb_putbits(encoded1, encix1, ch, 8)
          ch = 128 + Int(k / 64) Mod 64
          Call bb_putbits(encoded1, encix1, ch, 8)
          ch = 128 + k Mod 64
          Call bb_putbits(encoded1, encix1, ch, 8)
          j = j + 4
        ElseIf k > &H7FF Then ' 7FF-FFFF 3 bytes
          ch = &HE0 + Int(k / &H1000) Mod 16
          Call bb_putbits(encoded1, encix1, ch, 8)
          ch = 128 + Int(k / 64) Mod 64
          Call bb_putbits(encoded1, encix1, ch, 8)
          ch = 128 + k Mod 64
          Call bb_putbits(encoded1, encix1, ch, 8)
          j = j + 3
        ElseIf k > &H7F Then ' 2 bytes
          ch = &HC0 + Int(k / 64) Mod 32
          Call bb_putbits(encoded1, encix1, ch, 8)
          ch = 128 + k Mod 64
          Call bb_putbits(encoded1, encix1, ch, 8)
          j = j + 2
        Else
          ch = k Mod 256
          Call bb_putbits(encoded1, encix1, ch, 8)
          j = j + 1
        End If
      End If
    Wend
    Select Case eb(i, 1)
      Case 1:
        If (j Mod 3) = 1 Then
          Call bb_putbits(encoded1, encix1, r, 4)
        ElseIf (j Mod 3) = 2 Then
          Call bb_putbits(encoded1, encix1, r, 7)
        End If
      Case 2:
        If (j Mod 2) = 1 Then Call bb_putbits(encoded1, encix1, r, 6)
    End Select
'MsgBox "blk[" & i & "] t:" & eb(i,1) & "from " & eb(i,2) & " to " & eb(i,3) + eb(i,2) & " bits=" & encix1
  Next i
  Call bb_putbits(encoded1, encix1, 0, 4) ' end of chain
  If (encix1 Mod 8) <> 0 Then  ' round to byte
    Call bb_putbits(encoded1, encix1, 0, 8 - (encix1 Mod 8))
  End If
  ' padding
  i = (qrp(5) - qrp(3) * qrp(4)) * 8
  If encix1 > i Then
    err = "Encode length error"
    Exit Function
  End If
  ' padding 0xEC,0x11,0xEC,0x11...
  Do While encix1 < i
    Call bb_putbits(encoded1, encix1, &HEC11, 16)
  Loop
  ' doplnime ECC
  i = qrp(3) * qrp(4) 'ppoly, pmemptr , psize , plen , pblocks
  Call qr_rs(&H11D, encoded1, qrp(5) - i, i, qrp(4))
'Call arr2hexstr(encoded1)
  encix1 = qrp(5)
  ' Pole pro vystup
  ReDim qrarr(0)
  ReDim qrarr(1, qrp(2) * 24& + 24&) ' 24 bytes per row
  qrarr(0, 0) = 0
  ch = 0
  Call bb_putbits(qrsync1, ch, Array(&HFE, &H82, &HBA, &HBA, &HBA, &H82, &HFE, 0), 64)
  Call qr_mask(qrarr, qrsync1, 8, 0, 0) ' sync UL
  Call qr_mask(qrarr, 0, 8, 8, 0)   ' fmtinfo UL under - bity 14..9 SYNC 8
  Call qr_mask(qrarr, qrsync1, 8, 0, siz - 7) ' sync UR ( o bit vlevo )
  Call qr_mask(qrarr, 0, 8, 8, siz - 8)   ' fmtinfo UR - bity 7..0
  Call qr_mask(qrarr, qrsync1, 8, siz - 7, 0) ' sync DL (zasahuje i do quiet zony)
  Call qr_mask(qrarr, 0, 8, siz - 8, 0)   ' blank nad DL
  For i = 0 To 6
    x = qr_bit(qrarr, -1, i, 8, 0) ' svisle fmtinfo UL - bity 0..5 SYNC 6,7
    x = qr_bit(qrarr, -1, i, siz - 8, 0) ' svisly blank pred UR
    x = qr_bit(qrarr, -1, siz - 1 - i, 8, 0) ' svisle fmtinfo DL - bity 14..8
  Next
  x = qr_bit(qrarr, -1, 7, 8, 0) ' svisle fmtinfo UL - bity 0..5 SYNC 6,7
  x = qr_bit(qrarr, -1, 7, siz - 8, 0) ' svisly blank pred UR
  x = qr_bit(qrarr, -1, 8, 8, 0) ' svisle fmtinfo UL - bity 0..5 SYNC 6,7
  x = qr_bit(qrarr, -1, siz - 8, 8, 1) ' black dot DL
  If qrp(13) <> 0 Or qrp(14) <> 0 Then ' versioninfo
  ' UR ver 0 1 2;3 4 5;...;15 16 17
  ' LL ver 0 3 6 9 12 15;1 4 7 10 13 16; 2 5 8 11 14 17
    k = 65536 * qrp(13) + 256& * qrp(14) + 1& * qrp(15)
    c = 0: r = 0
    For i = 0 To 17
      ch = k Mod 2
      x = qr_bit(qrarr, -1, r, siz - 11 + c, ch) ' UR ver
      x = qr_bit(qrarr, -1, siz - 11 + c, r, ch) ' DL ver
      c = c + 1
      If c > 2 Then c = 0: r = r + 1
      k = Int(k / 2&)
    Next
  End If
  c = 1
  For i = 8 To siz - 9 ' sync lines
    x = qr_bit(qrarr, -1, i, 6, c) ' vertical on column 6
    x = qr_bit(qrarr, -1, 6, i, c) ' horizontal on row 6
    c = (c + 1) Mod 2
  Next
  ' other syncs
  ch = 0
  Call bb_putbits(qrsync2, ch, Array(&H1F, &H11, &H15, &H11, &H1F), 40)
  ch = 6
  Do While ch > 0 And qrp(6 + ch) = 0
    ch = ch - 1
  Loop
  If ch > 0 Then
    For c = 0 To ch
      For r = 0 To ch
        ' corners
        If (c <> 0 Or r <> 0) And _
           (c <> ch Or r <> 0) And _
           (c <> 0 Or r <> ch) Then
          Call qr_mask(qrarr, qrsync2, 5, qrp(r + 6) - 2, qrp(c + 6) - 2)
        End If
      Next r
    Next c
  End If
 ' qr_fill(parr as Variant, psiz%, pb as Variant, pblocks%, pdlen%, ptlen%)
 ' vyplni pole parr (psiz x 24 bytes) z pole pb pdlen = pocet dbytes, pblocks = bloku, ptlen celkem
  Call qr_fill(qrarr, siz, encoded1, qrp(4), qrp(5) - qrp(3) * qrp(4), qrp(5))
  mask = 8 ' auto
  i = InStr(poptions, "mask=")
  If i > 0 Then mask = val(Mid(poptions, i + 5, 1))
  If mask < 0 Or mask > 7 Then
    j = -1
    For mask = 0 To 7
      GoSub addmm
      i = qr_xormask(qrarr, siz, mask, False)
'      MsgBox "score mask " & mask & " is " & i
      If i < j Or j = -1 Then j = i: s = mask
    Next mask
    mask = s
'    MsgBox "best is " & mask & " with score " & j
  End If
  GoSub addmm
  i = qr_xormask(qrarr, siz, mask, True)
  ascimatrix = ""
  For r = 0 To siz Step 2
    s = 0
    For c = 0 To siz Step 2
      If (c Mod 8) = 0 Then
        ch = qrarr(1, s + 24 * r)
        If r < siz Then i = qrarr(1, s + 24 * (r + 1)) Else i = 0
        s = s + 1
      End If
      ascimatrix = ascimatrix _
         & Chr(97 + (ch Mod 4) + 4 * (i Mod 4))
      ch = Int(ch / 4)
      i = Int(i / 4)
    Next
    ascimatrix = ascimatrix & vbNewLine
  Next r
  ReDim qrarr(0)
  qr_gen = ascimatrix
  Exit Function
addmm:
  k = ecl * 8 + mask
  ' poly: 101 0011 0111
  Call qr_bch_calc(k, &H537)
'MsgBox "mask :" & hex(k,3) & " " & hex(k xor &H5412,3)
  k = k Xor &H5412 ' micro xor &H4445
  r = 0
  c = siz - 1
  For i = 0 To 14
    ch = k Mod 2
    k = Int(k / 2)
    x = qr_bit(qrarr, -1, r, 8, ch) ' svisle fmtinfo UL - bity 0..5 SYNC 6,7 .... 8..14 dole
    x = qr_bit(qrarr, -1, 8, c, ch) ' vodorovne odzadu 0..7 ............ 8,SYNC,9..14
    c = c - 1
    r = r + 1
    If i = 7 Then c = 7: r = siz - 7
    If i = 5 Then r = r + 1 ' preskoc sync vodorvny
    If i = 8 Then c = c - 1 ' preskoc sync svisly
  Next
  Return
End Function  ' qr_gen
```

Comment: Just noticed that HotRhodium posted a modified version of  barcode-vba-macro-only, but the problems he is having seem unrelated to my issues: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/977826-vbe-stops-no-error-working-shapes-qr-codes.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Why this happens**

Through some debugging, I found that the original implementation messes up the starting position of different encodings (which it stores in array `eb`): after encoding the "Recipient First and Last Name" including newline and "DE" as "Byte", it probably tries to switch to "Decimal" or "Alphanum" encoding (only 3.33 or 5.5 bit per character instead of 8)... but then falls back to encoding in "Byte" format and thereby gets the starting position wrong.

**The solution**

I have now added some error checking to the code which manually removes the stuttering.

You can find my improved code on [Github](https://github.com/JonasHeidelberg/barcode-vba-macro-only), see in particular [barcody.bas](https://github.com/JonasHeidelberg/barcode-vba-macro-only/blob/master/barcody.bas).

The key addition is this part:

```
  i = 1
  While i < (ebcnt - 1)
    If eb(i, 2) + eb(i, 3) <> eb(i + 1, 2) Then
        ' oops, this should not happen. First document it:
        Debug.Print ("eb() rows " & i & " and " & i + 1 & " are overlapping!")
        ' Now Lets see if we can fix it:
        wasfixed = False
        For k = i To 1 Step -1
            If eb(k, 2) = eb(i + 1, 2) Then
                ' okay, the row k to i seem to be contained in i+1 and following. Delete k to i ...
                For j = k To ebcnt - (i - k + 1) ' ... by copying upwards all later rows...
                    eb(j, 1) = eb(j + (i - k + 1), 1)
                    eb(j, 2) = eb(j + (i - k + 1), 2)
                    eb(j, 3) = eb(j + (i - k + 1), 3)
                    eb(j, 4) = eb(j + (i - k + 1), 4)
                Next j
                ebcnt = ebcnt - (i - k + 1) ' and correcting the total rowcount
                wasfixed = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next k
        If Not (wasfixed) Then
            MsgBox ("The input text analysis failed - entering debug mode...")
            Debug.Assert False
        End If
    End If
    i = i + 1
  Wend
```

Comment: It's awesome that you took time to debug this and improved the original code.  Now this QR code would be a lot more robust!  Too bad I can't upvote more than once but maybe other people would get to enjoy this too.

Comment: Note there seem to be even more bugs in barcode-vba-macro-only... I added a quickfix on GitHub, but this thing would need some serious attention to be properly fixed...

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed this same issue with certain character being a trigger for this problem when it comes after something. In your case, it looks like something after "DE"  Since I didn't write the code I haven't thoroughly search in the code why this would trigger a repeat but I'm guessing that some of the hex conversion in the function causes this problem.  In my case, I avoided the issue by having a space in front of the entire string being input to the generator.  For some reasons, having the space at the beginning somehow prevent the triggering of the repeat. The reader program that reads the barcode in my case would remove the space from the string anyway so it doesn't matter.

I don't know whether it's a problem for your application, but try putting a blank space (" ") in front of the problematic string (DE86672500200000123456 )and see whether that works.

```
BCD
001
1
SCT
SOLADES1HDB
Recipient First and Last Name
 DE86672500200000123456 
EUR123.45
```

Comment: Thanks, I will give that a try... I guess it might be a start, but I don't think I will rely on it permanently since I need my QR Codes to work on anyones end device/ banking app...

Comment: Not sure whether having it in pure VBA is a requirement for you. You could use many of the QR code modules in .NET and compile it as a DLL and you import dll function in VBA to use a more stable QR library.  I have used Zen Barcode and it's been very stable in C#  and VB.NET.  https://barcoderender.codeplex.com/

Comment: A DLL would also be okay I guess... I was just looking for a low-effort solution ;-)

Comment: I analyzed the code some more... Seems the code fails when it considers to switch to numeric encoding for a substring (8 or 9 digits seems to be the minimum length for it to consider that). Space before DE didn't help in my case, but 2-3 spaces in the middle of the number works at least for the 1 app I tested...