# Multiple functions with same name in vba self duplicating

Tags: excel, vba, fonts, barcode

I found some code here [Generating 2D (PDF417 or QR) barcodes using Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16143331/generating-2d-pdf417-or-qr-barcodes-using-excel-vba) by Jonas Heilderberg. When I try to run Call RenderQRCode("Sheet1", "A13", "QR Value") I get an "ambiguous name detected: RenderQRCode" error.
Can anyone help and tell me where Call RenderQRCode("Sheet1", "A13", "QR Value") should be getting placed and how it should be called?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you name a VBA code module or a worksheet module as "RenderQRCode"?

Comment: No, I just put all that in one module.

Comment: That error is telling you there's more than one thing with the name "RenderQRCode" - candidate "things" include Subs, Functions, module names, and worksheet codenames.  Check those and make sure you have only one "RenderQRCode"

Comment: In my haste to try to get it working I had saved the same macro twice, would that have been the issue? Is putting this =Call RenderQRCode("Sheet1", "A13", "QR Value") in a cell wrong also?

Comment: No you'd run the code using (eg) `RenderQRCode "Sheet1", "A13", "QR Value"` in a different Sub in that workbook.

Comment: Thanks for your help Tim, I got it working :-)